# Detect business hours on dayclick event

Tags: fullcalendar

How can i detect if a dayclick event was trigger in a business hour or out of them?
I need to do some action only if click event was in business hours.

Now, i can set the business hours and styling them with css to show in red background and a different cursor, but i have no idea how to detect that in the dayclick event :(

My code is:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    theme: true,
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    allDaySlot: false,
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay,listMonth'
    },
    contentHeight: 'auto',
    defaultDate: '2017-02-17',
    navLinks: true,
    editable: false,
    eventLimit: true,
    minTime: "09:00:00",
    maxTime: "19:00:00",
    slotMinutes: 30,
    slotDuration: "00:30:00",
    slotLabelInterval: 30,
    slotLabelFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
    defaultTimedEventDuration: "00:29:00",
    forceEventDuration: true,
    businessHours: {
        dow: [1,2,3,4,5,6], // NOT SUNDAY
        start: '09:00:00',
        end: '19:00:00'
    },
    dayClick: function(fechaElegida, todoElDia, jsEvento, vista) {
        // HERE DO THINGS
        // I want some like
        // if( IS BUSINESS HOURS ){
        //    DO SOMETHING
        // }else{
        //    DO OTHER THINGS
        // }
    },
    eventClick: function(calEvento, jsEvento, vista) {
        // MORE CODE. NOT RELEVANT
    },
    viewRender: function(view,element) { //restricting available dates to 2 moths in future
        var now = new Date();
        var end = new Date();
        end.setMonth(now.getMonth() + 1); //Adjust as needed
        if ( end < view.end) {
            $("#calendar .fc-next-button").hide();
            return false;
        }else {
            $("#calendar .fc-next-button").show();
        }
        if ( view.start < now) {
            $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").hide();
            return false;
        }else {
            $("#calendar .fc-prev-button").show();
        }
    },
    events: [
        {
            title: 'Test event',
            start: '2017-02-17 09:00:00',
            id: '14',
            skey: 'rra7r15pm8',
            color: '#10A834'
        }
    ]
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can we please see some sample code?

Comment: Ok. Post edited to add my code. Thanks.

Comment: So is your schedule 9 to nine Monday to Saturday?

Comment: Monday to saturday, 9:00 to 19:00,
I show sunday with a red background and a "not-allowed" cursor, but is only makeup. If i clicked on sunday, still activating the dayclick event.

Comment: I have added my answer below, please take a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, the answer was to use a function "not in fullcalendar" that compare the selected day with an array identical to array **businessHours: {dow:[1,2,3,4,5,6]}**

Before the call to fullCalendar, i create an array with the available days (same of bussiness hours dow)

```
var DaysOK = [1,2,3,4,5,6];
```

An then, inside the dayClick event:

```
dayClick: function(mydate, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
  var mydateObj = new Date(mydate);
  var chosenDay = mydateObj.getUTCDay();
  if( daysOK.indexOf(chosenDay) >= 0 ){
    // DAY OK
  else{
    // DAY NOT AVALAIBLE
  }
}
```

Testing and working well.

Comment: How does this check if it is occurring during the right time of day 9am to 7 pm?

Comment: In this case, i don't need to check de time, because the view limit the hours that you can choose and never you can pick up a not business hour.

Comment: Oh, ok. Can you still mark my answer as correct so I get a few points for helping?

Answer (score 1):

your dayclick event should receive the current date as part of the function call, so all you need to do is check that against your business hours to see if a time selected is during business hours. below you will see a small function that gets passed a date object and will return a one if the date passed was during business hours and a zero if not. The way that the function works is that it first checks the day of the week to ensure that the day selected isnt a sunday, after that it will check the hour selected and see if it is between 9 and 18, i use 18 instead of 19 in my function because using 18 as the hour parameter means that you are including times up to 18:59:59 which is exactly one second before you close.

```
function checkIfBusinessHours(date) {
  if (date.getDay() == 0) {
    return 0;
  } else {
    if (date.getHours() <= 18 && date.getHours() >= 9) {
      return 1;
    } else {
      return 0;
    }
  }
}
```

and a sample of how this function may be utilized would be the following:

```
dayClick: function(fechaElegida, todoElDia, jsEvento, vista) {
    // HERE DO THINGS
    // I want some like
   if(checkIfBusinessHours(fechaElegia)==1){
    //    DO SOMETHING
   }else{
    //    DO OTHER THINGS
   }
}
```

a live demo of the code may be found: [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/jRFYE/885/)

Comment: Ok. I will test it in a while. Then, is not a solution "inside" the fullcalendar functions? There is no way to get the "business hours" from some object in fullcalendar and use it to compare instead of directly write "18" or "9" or the day "0" in the function?
Thanks

Comment: If you simply copy the code from the function and place it into dayclick it will do the same thing and I will look into rewriting the code to get the business hours from the variable in fullcalandar

Comment: Your original function not work in my case. I have to do some changes.
First, i have to covnert "fechaElegida" into a date object, and then use getDay function. But the main idea works. Thanks.

Comment: @lesterfibla no problem, if you could mark this answer as correct that would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following

```
const isNonBusinessSlot = Boolean((arg.jsEvent.target as HTMLDivElement).className === 'fc-non-business');
```

Comment: +1 as this does not require you to do additional checks. It does get the info from the event.jsEvent.target. And confirmed on my end that it works.